# iptables drop fake ip packets

Tags: linux, networking, iptables

I'm trying to drop all packets from the internet that use a fake ip address so they appear to come locally.

Do I need both lines or only the first ?

```
--append INPUT ! --in-interface lo --source 127.0.0.0/8 --jump DROP

--append INPUT ! --in-interface lo --destination 127.0.0.0/8 --jump DROP
```

Comment: You should consider setting /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/all/rp_filter. See here http://www.linuxsecurity.com/content/view/111337/65/ for a description.

Answer (score 0):

You could use both, neither should exist really so blocking shouldn't hurt.

I'd also add rules for blocking [non-routing IPs](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc1918.html) coming from outside your network.